# Advice for code simplification for joint table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2

I need advice for my code simplification. I am using Struts 2, Spring, and Hibernate as framework.

**File DAO:**

```
public List<Model> getData() throws HibernateException {

    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    List<Object[]> res = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    String query = "SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.bridge_id = table2.bridge_id";
    res = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createSQLQuery(query)
            .list();

    for (Object[] row : res) {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setName((String) row[1]);
        model.setDate((Date) row[2]);

        list.add(model);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I try using

```
while(res.next()){ ... }
```

but `next()` is not function in my project, like I am using `size()` to count size of the list rather than `length` of array.

for some reason I dont like to define function value in loop using `row[0]`, what I want is to define the value as `row["name"]`.

Comment: You said `"what i want is define value as row["name"]"` but what do you mean? How would you like to evaluate `row["name"]`? It's not syntactically correct in Java.

Comment: it's just like, I tried to make it like a procedural array call

Comment: I think this is cause i am using native query, not a procedural query

Comment: If you are using native query the data is returned in the row format without specific metadata available to specific entity. In this case you should map a metadata information yourself, otherwise to return multiple objects from the query you should use  hql.

Comment: Thats my question in this treat, can you give me example to convert native query to use in map, to return multiple objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was posible two ways to map column  names to use with row data `Object[]` which contains only values.

1. Map column names to indeces.

```
    Map<String, int> map = new HashMap<>()
    map.put("name", 0); 
    map.put("date", 1);
    for (Object[] row : res) {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setName((String) row[map.get("name")]);
        model.setDate((Date) row[map.get("date")]);
        list.add(model);
     }
```

2. Map `Object[]` to `Map<String, Object>` and use previous mapping

```
    Map<String, int> map = new HashMap<>()
    map.put("name", 0); 
    map.put("date", 1);
    
    for (Object[] row : res) {
        Model model = new Model();
        Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("name", row[map.get("name")]);
        map2.put("date", row[map.get("date")]
        model.setName((String) map2.get("name"));
        model.setDate((Date) map2.get("date"));
        list.add(model);
     }
```

You can create an adapter class for `row` which contains both mapping. The adapter takes `Object[]` as a constructor parameter. Then use a function `getValue(String)` which returns an `Object` from the second map.